# Compilation failed while building apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, build, compilation

When I'm building apk its showing this error and I cant solve this.

> error: '{' expected
>
> error: '{' expected
>
> error: reached end of file while parsing

This is what appearing all the time

```
//Set to true if you would like to support popup windows, e.g. for Facebook login
    public static boolean MULTI_WINDOWS = true;
    //If you would like to show the splash screen for an additional amount of time after page load, define it here (MS)
    public static int SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 0;
    //Permissions required to use the app (should also be in manifest.xml)
    public static String[] PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = new String[]{}; //Manifest.permission.PERMISSION_NAME
    //Always use the app name as actionbar title (only applies for if USE_DRAWER is false and number of tabs == 1)
    public static boolean STATIC_TOOLBAR_TITLE = false;
    //Load a web page when no internet connection was found (must be in assets). Leave empty to show dialog.
    public static String NO_CONNECTION_PAGE = "";
    //The image/icon used for in the drawer header
    public interface DRAWER_ICON = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    //Show interstitials when browsing web pages (or only during drawer/tab navigation)
    public static final boolean INTERSTITIAL_PAGE_LOAD = true;
    //The frequency in which interstitial ads are shown
    public static final interface INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL = 0;
}
```

Comment: try to enclose all of your classes with a "{ }", possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902788/error-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing

Comment: try to paste more code: it will be easier to help